# Why are JavaScript string arrays interpreted differently by jQuery template {{each}} tags vs. jQuery $.each?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Obligatory [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/wuEyp/).

When I run an array of strings through jQuery's `$.each` function, I get what I expect.

```
$.each(["abc", "123", "def", "456"], function (i, val) {
    $("<li></li>").text("source[" + i + "]: " + val).appendTo(".eachResults");
    // run for each string in the array ("abc", "123", ...)
});
```

When I run the same array of strings through jQuery Template's `{{each}}` operator, though, it treats it as a two dimensional array of `char`s.

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
<ul>
    {{each(i, prop) $data}}
    {{if $data.hasOwnProperty(i)}}
    <li>
        source[${i}]: ${$data[i]}
        {{! run for each char of each string in array (0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c", 0:"1", 1:"2", 3:"3", ...)}}
    </li>
    {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>

$("#testTemplate").tmpl(["abc", "123", "def", "456"]).appendTo(".tmplResults");
```

Since the `i` in the template always seems to reference correctly into `$data`, I don't really have any clue how this indexing works at all. It seems like `i` would need to be a two-dimensional index to work correctly, but it doesn't appear to be (`typeof (i) === "number"`).

### Follow-up question

@mblase75 certainly explained the issue here. Unfortunately, given this was a subset of my actual code, it turned out to just bring up a different [question about recursively calling an `{{each}}` template when you come across an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436189/how-do-i-prevent-jquery-template-from-digging-too-deeply-on-a-string-array-in-a-r).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that templates are an implicit loop. Your original `{{each}}` was looping through each character in each string -- the template was looping through each string in the array.

This will give you the desired result (more or less):

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <li>
        source[]: ${$data}
    </li>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wuEyp/10/ uses the above code. The index is gone because the template doesn't seem to provide for it at the "root" level.

http://jsfiddle.net/wuEyp/11 will add the indexing back in using a function. For some reason, I can't do it properly with a closure.

Comment: Remember that templates are an implicit loop. Your original `{{each}}` was looping through each character in each string -- the *template* was looping through each string in the array.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wuEyp/11/ will add the indexing back in. For some reason I can't do it properly with a closure....

Comment: I think your first comment is the actual answer to the question (still confirming). Just edit your own answer and put your comments in there and I will probably end up accepting it.

Comment: I'm definitely going to have to just call this question good and start a new one more specific than this. My problem is a recursive {{each}} template (basic JS reflection) that is going too deep on arrays of strings. I just need to figure out how to shortcut that recursion on such arrays. That's what I get for trying to cut out just enough to present the problem: an answer to the question but not my problem. :P

Comment: if you happen to have a way to avoid this implicit loop, there is a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436189/how-do-i-prevent-jquery-template-from-digging-too-deeply-on-a-string-array-in-a-r) out now.